# Calculating averages and more

Tags: tables, calculations

I am translating a Word document into LaTeX as a learning experience. Now there is this table, that already has hard-coded values. However, I would like to have it generic, so that changing a single number inside the .tex file changes the number of rows of the column. All values are calculated based on the key of the row, by the following algorithm.

> Given a real number, calculate a number a dice (6-sided) and an
>   integer modifier, which is no larger than +- 3. The [expected
>   value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of the resulting
>   modified dice throw should equal the input number with error no higher
>   that 0.5. Make the algorithm deterministic.

*Can this be done? Please propose further reading.*

Something in the lines of:

```
[dice, mod] foo(expected)
    dice = floor(expected / 3.5)
    mod = floor(expected - dice * 3.5)
```

But an algorithm, that balances the use of positive and negative modifiers would be better. Also, gracefully handling values below 3.5 would be great (always including at least one die).

*As an example, 12 would output 3 dice +1 modifier for a total expected value of 11.5.*

The source table is this, but it needn't be followed precisely.

[image]

Comment: Please, someone more experienced edit the tags of the question. I browsed the first 3 pages of most popular tags, but found nothing.

Comment: I would suggest the `calculator` package in combination with `forloop` package. It should be possible to calculate averages then. Can you post an image file of that mentioned table?

Comment: @Christian, sure, later tonight. In short, the row number is the row ID as well. We have three columns: `*1`, `*2/3` and `*1/2`. Each cell should contain the row ID, multiplied by the column ... um heading. The number of rows is currently 30, but I would like to be flexible!

Comment: You mean, that the number of rows should be flexible? The multiplication is not really the problem, but the 'dynamical' number of rows. This can be done from within `LaTeX`, but I suppose, it is no joy to do so ;-)

Comment: @Christian, I am yet to learn constructing tables, when a little free time pops up. That sound fairly easy and [well-documented](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). I was thinking doing math would be awkward, hence this question on feasibility. So constructing a table, that has a number of rows, defined somewhere else, is a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are aiming at?

[image: dynamic table]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xintfrac}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

    % dice = floor(expected / 3.5)
    % mod = floor(expected - dice * 3.5)

\def\rows {12}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline
  expected & dice & mod \\
  \hline
  \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{\rows}}
  \do
  { #1 & \xinttheexpr floor(#1 / 3.5)\relax 
     & \xinttheexpr floor(#1 - floor(#1/3.5)*3.5)\relax \\ }
  \hline
\end{tabular}

% \begin{tabular}{ccc}
%   $*1$&$*2/3$&$*1/2$\\
%   \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{30}}
%   \do
%   {$#1$&$\xintRound {4}{\xintMul {#1}{2/3}}$&$\xintRound {2}{\xintMul {#1}{1/2}}$\\}
% \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I am not sure to have well understood. Here is the table from my first answer (commented out code above).

[image: dynamic table]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xintfrac}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  $*1$&$*2/3$&$*1/2$\\
  \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{30}}
  \do
  {$#1$&$\xintRound {4}{\xintMul {#1}{2/3}}$&$\xintRound {2}{\xintMul {#1}{1/2}}$\\}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If the number of rows is too big to fit on a page, using a longtable is possible, or the `TeX` primitive `\halign`.

Comment: Hi. I added an example!

Comment: there is no problem to implement your formula using `xintfrac` or more conveniently `xintexpr`: for example `\xinttheexpr floor(#1/3.5)\relax`, but could you please add an image of a sample table, I have some difficulty figuring out how it is supposed to be. You can use `\xintFor*` with explicit sequence `{{1.2}{3.7}{10.9}}` rather than an arithmetic one. Or without the star `\xintFor` accepts a comma separated list `{1.2, 3.7, 10.9}`.

Comment: Great! Now to understand it :D

Comment: I was going to say the same vz the table image you have now included ;-)

Comment: how does `As an example, 12 would output 3 dice +1 modifier for a total expected value of 11.5.` relate to row number `12` in the image you uploaded? I still don't get it.

Comment: Throwing 3 dice, summing them and adding 1 to the total will ofter result in a result of 12.

Comment: it will equally often produce a result of `11`, I suspect the original question would be better phrased if the goal was to obtain some *interval of trust*, according to a pre-defined coefficient of certainty (`90%`, `95%`, etc...), but well I was never well versed in statistics.